# Checking an object list with the same object list

Tags: java, android, collision-detection, libgdx

I have a problem with checking objects in a list with the same objects. I have an object list with different type of objects like, bullets, enemies and random background objects.
Now I want to check if some objects collide with each other, like bullets with enemies.
The problem is that when I put the same for loop within the for loop with both the same objects, i don't get the behavior i was expecting... Anyone knows a better way to handle this?

The left image shows that bullets are not moving anymore, the right show the situation when i remove the loop within the loop.

https://www.dropbox.com/s/92tnxizxdneqgz3/ss1.png

EDIT: The different strings are read from a script, I am aiming for maximal flexibility. That is also the reason why I don't want different collections of each type of object. The collision was working when I did that.

```
for (Object o : objects) {

    if (o.behavior.equals("aggressive")) {
        o.aggressive(ship.x, ship.y, ship.z);
    }

    if (o.behavior.equals("missile")) {
        o.missile();

        if (o.type.equals("bullet_player")) {
            for (Object n : objects) {
                             //doesn't matter what i put here
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Solution:**

I got it working, the problem appears to lie in nesting an for loop of an arraylist within an other. What i finally did is this: I cloned the arraylist, check the cloned list with the original object list, i check if the object is the same and if not I do the collision check.

Comment: May be an example output you are expecting may help in understanding the issue.

Comment: Err, just for clarification: `Object` isn't `java.lang.Object` - correct? Otherwise this will never compile.

Comment: @Andreas_D No it isn't. ;) It does compile/work.

Comment: Why don't you keep separate collections for each type of objects?

Comment: Post the Object. or collide() method. Also, why did you base your whole game on strings? that's what enums are for.

Comment: The different strings are read from a script, I am aiming for maximal flexibility. That is also the reason why I don't want different collections of each type of object. The collision was working when I did that.

Answer (score 3):

The standard approach is this, which will compare each pairing once:

```
for(int i=0; i<objects.size(); i++)
    for(int j=i+1; j<objects.size(); j++)
        //.... compare objects[i] and objects[j] for collision etc
```

As your game world gets more complex, consider placing objects in a [spatial index](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spatial_database#Spatial_index) instead.

Comment: his Object is the uppermost interface, so not all of them are checked for collision. but i changed my mind about the downvote, it seems like it's an Object full of string members. how intuitive.

Comment: This does not seem to get the desireable result. What i finally did is this: I cloned the arraylist, i check if the object is the same and if not I do the collision check.

Answer (score 0):

The nested loop shouldn't be a problem. The following example, where I have some iterators running on the same collection, works as expected:

```
public static void main(String a[]) {
    List<String> strings = Arrays.asList("a", "b", "c");
    for (String s: strings) {
        for (String t:strings) {
            System.out.println(s + "/" + t);
        }
    }
}
```

Looks to me like the problem is within your collision detection. You may have false positives (collisions detected where no collision happened)

Comment: i thought he had each object collide with itself but he checks their types before collision. assuming collision-checks are proper or at least somewhat accurate.

Comment: @Andreas_D The weird thing is that the behavior occurs when I only put 
for (Object n : objects) { 
}
in the loop. Even if i don't check for collision.